# Access window.crypto from vscode web extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, cryptography, vscode-extensions

I need to migrate my vscode extension to web (vscode.dev). So I need to polyfil some node.js libraries.
I would like to replace `crypto` (rsa) node.js by web api `window.crypto`, but I didn't find a way  to access `window` global object from vscode runtime. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto)

I tried `crypto-browserify` library, but it doesn't have `generateKeyPair` implementation
It's a little bit better with `node-forge` library

But I would like to use build-in browser functionality

Be able to use `window.crypto` API from vscode web runtime.

- not from vscode.WebView, but from extension.ts for example

Thanks